# TCP/IP Client for NodeJS Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, socket.io, tcpclient

Is it possible to communicate with a NodeJS Socket.IO
server with a TCP/IP Socket Client?

The server below is from 
[http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/more-responsive-single-page-applications-
with-angularjs-socketio-creating-the-library--cms-21738](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/more-responsive-single-page-applications-%20with-angularjs-socketio-creating-the-library--cms-21738).
It accepts connection, then services an 'echo'. Is it possible to format
the connection and 'echo' message from TCP/IP Socket?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

server.listen(8080, function(){
   console.log('Listening at port 8080');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) 
{
   var _socket = socket;
   console.log('Someone connected');
   socket.on('echo', function (data) {
     _socket.emit('echo', data);
   });
});
```

Any help or example is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is: no. The Websocket is a socket over the HTTP protocol, it works like a socket but is not a simple socket.

But you can use a Websocket client implementation (a simple socket + some protocol rules) in a console application to establish connection with a remote Websocket. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws)

Comment: In the end, a Websocket client _is_ a TCP/IP client (one that happens to talk the correct protocols).

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Sorry, but I left out the following requirement: the client cannot contain javascript (must be C/C++ only).

Comment: So you will need use the libwebsockets for C/C++, here is a link with a demo client app:

https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/blob/master/test-server/test-client.c

I hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a vanilla socket client in C/C++ on the client.
Then, in one nodeJS app, I implemented both a TCP/IP server
and a WebSocket server. This produced the behavior I was
looking for.